# sbs 2011 certificate not renewing properly

Tags: certificate

I'm working on an SBS 2011 server here, the client advised she could no longer access mail on her laptop because her certificate had expired. The company uses a self assigned certificate. So I run the Fix my network tool in the SBS console, it says it has renewed the certificate, and on checking, indeed it did. However, the process did not update the certificate package to give to the client to install on her laptop. So we have a problem. How do I get the system to update the certificate installation package? If it cannot then where can I locate the certificate that was renewed to manually put it in the package. 
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: IIS restarted ? or simply restart the server.. test again after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renewing SBS2011 Exchange Self-Signed Certificate w/o changing home page in IE?](http://serverfault.com/questions/526221/renewing-sbs2011-exchange-self-signed-certificate-w-o-changing-home-page-in-ie)